# Android:Implementing twitPic

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j, twitpic

This topic seems to be really tricky for me. I want a right head start to uploading images onto twitPic from my android application. I have no clue of where to start from.

Answer (score 0):

You can find what you're looking for at http://code.google.com/p/twitpic4j/

Comment: I'm getting an IOException on using this code. It must be a simple problem. Kindly help.

Comment: It was working for me but now its not working. Its throwing IncorrectUserNameException. I think thers some problem in API